# Symfony2 Elastica bundle (elasticsearch) - possible to restrict only 'active' items?

Tags: php, symfony, elasticsearch

I'm currently using the [FOQElasticaBundle](https://github.com/Exercise/FOQElasticaBundle/) to interact with my elasticsearch server, but I can't seem to find a way to restrict the search results based on an "active" flag on each entity. Is it possible to set this in the configuration somehow? Here is my current config:

```
foq_elastica:
    clients:
        default: { host: localhost, port: 9200 }

    indexes:
        website:
            client: default
            types:
                story:
                    mappings:
                        title: { boost: 8 }
                        summary: { boost: 5 }
                        text: { boost: 3 }
                        author:
                    persistence:
                        driver: orm # orm, mongodb, propel are available
                        model: Joe\Bundle\StoryBundle\Entity\Story
                        provider:
                        listener:
                        finder:
```

I can't just exclude inactive stories at the controller/view level because this will mess up the pagination - I'll need to have a consistent number of items per page so the search will need to filter out any stories where `active` is false (or 0). I'm sure this must be possible, but does anybody know how.

Thanks.

**EDIT**

After having no luck specifying a custom `query_builder_method` for the provider, I had a shot at specifying a custom repository instead and building my query. But I haven't been able to get this to work yet either. Here is my search method:

```
public function findByQueryString($queryString)
{

    $builder = new \Elastica_Query_Builder();
    $builder
        ->queryString()
            ->field('query', $queryString)
        ->queryStringClose()
        ->filter()
            ->term()
                ->field('active', 1)
            ->termClose()
        ->filterClose()
    ;
    // TODO check published date...

    return $this->findPaginated($builder);
}
```

Which produces the following JSON:

```
{
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
            "query": "story"
        },
        "filter": {
            "term": {
                "active": "1"
            }
        }
    },
    "from": 0,
    "size": 10
}
```

But it doesn't appear to like the "term" part of the filter for some reason. I was just attempting to mimic what is in the [elasticsearch documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/filter.html) but I admit I don't really know what I should be doing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible by using `Doctrine query builder`. [Read here](https://github.com/Exercise/FOQElasticaBundle/#use-a-custom-doctrine-query-builder).

```
    persistence:
            driver: orm
            model: Application\UserBundle\Entity\User
            provider:
                query_builder_method: createIsActiveQueryBuilder
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but this didn't work for me. The method was never being called - I spend a while thoroughly debugging through what was going on and the AbstractProvider that uses this query_builder_method config value was never called. It would seem findPaginated() doesn't make use of this.

Comment: Ignore my last comment. This did do the trick actually - I just needed to clear my cache and re-populate elasticsearch.

Answer (score 0):

OK this was 3 years ago, but new readers might like to read this answer.

==> It is actualy very simple and require no work.

Example, I have a Post entity with a 'published' boolean field.
Be sure to have the getter of this field in your entity class.
In this example, the getter is getPublished.
Then you can simply configure the listener in your config file that way.

```
 persistence:
     listener:
         is_indexable_callback: "getPublished"
```

[Here is the doc](https://github.com/Exercise/FOQElasticaBundle#checking-an-entity-method-for-listener)